how to initialize a derived set that has fewer elements than the original set im OPL, CPLEX
tuple Combination_L {
  int labrooms;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int labcourses;
};

{Combination_L} L = ...; 
                        
tuple Combination_T {
  int days;
  int slots;
};

{Combination_T} T = ...; 
                      
tuple Combination_L_T{
  int labrooms;
  int days;
  int slots;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int labcourses;
};

{Combination_L_T} V_l; 
execute {
 for (var p in L){
   for (var q in T){
     V_l.add(p.labrooms, 
             q.days,
             q.slots, 
             p.instructors, 
             p.studentgroups,
             p.labcourses);
   };
 }; 
};

I want to initialize a derived set Q_l, which represents all possible assignments of room, lecturer, student group and course for the laboratory planning level. These assignments fulfill the condition that the value of the fourth element of the quadruple is l, which means that the lecturer assigned to the quadruple has the value l. These assignments are derived from the variable set V_l
Hier ist my code:
{Combination_L} Q_l;

execute {
    for (var l in instructors) {
        Q_l += {<i, l, m, n> |
         <i, _, _, l, m, n> in V_l};
    };
};

I get a scripting parser error: missing expression.
Please tell me where I made a mistake.
Thanks so much!

You mix OPL modeling syntax and OPL scripting syntax.
You could use slicing:
tuple Combination_L {
  int labrooms;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int labcourses;
};


{Combination_L} L = {<1,2,3,4>,<2,3,4,5>};

tuple Combination_T {
  int days;
  int slots;
};

{Combination_T} T = {<1,2>,<2,3>};; 
                      
tuple Combination_L_T{
  int labrooms;
  int days;
  int slots;
  int instructors;
  int studentgroups;
  int labcourses;
};

{Combination_L_T} V_l; 
execute {
 for (var p in L){
   for (var q in T) {
     V_l.add(p.labrooms, 
             q.days,
             q.slots, 
             p.instructors, 
             p.studentgroups,
             p.labcourses);
   };
 }; 
};

{int} instructors={i.instructors | i in L};

{Combination_L_T} Q_l[i in instructors]={l |l in V_l :l.instructors==i};

{Combination_L} Q_i[i in instructors]={
<j.labrooms,j.days,j.slots,j.instructors> | j in Q_l[i]};
execute
{
  writeln(Q_l);
  writeln(Q_i);
};

gives
[{<1 1 2 2 3 4> <1 2 3 2 3 4>} {
        <2 1 2 3 4 5> <2 2 3 3 4 5>}]
 [{<1 1 2 2> <1 2 3 2>} {<2 1 2 3> <2 2 3 3>}]


Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that I need only four elements for Q_l. That means, that Q_l is a type of {Combination_L}.

Then add {Combination_L} Q_i[i in instructors]={
<j.labrooms,j.days,j.slots,j.instructors> | j in Q_l[i]};

Hi Alex, thank you soooooo much! I got it. Thanks also for your advice how to comment for a answer. I did not know.

Hi Alex, I have a question: how could it be, when the conditions of Q_l not only (i in instructrors) but also (i in instructors and m in studentgroups)?

I added {Combination_L_T} Q_l [a in instructors,b in studentgroups] =
{<i,m> | <i,m> in V_l : i.instructors == a && m.studentgroups == b}; but it was wrong.

{int} studentgroups={i.studentgroups | i in L};
{Combination_L_T} Q_l2 [a in instructors,b in studentgroups] =
{i | i in V_l : i.instructors == a && i.studentgroups == b};

Hi Alex, thanks a lot! Yes, I understood how it works.
